# How to summarise multiple average of columns?

Tags: python, sqlite

Right now I am doing the following:

```
c.execute("SELECT AVG(col1) from table")
avg_c1 = c.fetchall()[0]
c.execute("SELECT AVG(col2) from table")
avg_c2 = c.fetchall()[0]
c.execute("SELECT AVG(col3) from table")
avg_c3 = c.fetchall()[0]
c.execute("SELECT AVG(col4) from table")
avg_c4 = c.fetchall()[0]
c.execute("SELECT AVG(col5) from table")
avg_c5 = c.fetchall()[0]
c.execute("SELECT AVG(col6) from table")
avg_c6 = c.fetchall()[0]
```

I want to shorten my code by summarising these repeatitive lines. But I tried

```
c.execute("SELECT AVG(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) from table")
avg = c.fetchall()[0]
```

and it says wrong number of arguments for `AVG()`.

What would be the right way to format my code? Thanks!

Comment: You can do the average of one column AVG(col) and can't supply all the comma-separated column names.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT AVG(col)
FROM (
  SELECT col1 AS col FROM tab UNION ALL
  SELECT col2        FROM tab UNION ALL
  ...
  SELECT col6        FROM tab
) s
```

Comment: Hmmm thanks but i dont understand what the code means or is doing. I have seen this answer for other questions and thought it was for other purpose.  Is there any simple explanation or could you point me to some references to study? Thanks!

Comment: @LeongJunHao It basically transposes data from 6 columns into single column and then compute singe AVG

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is the same table, then you can do the following:

```
c.execute("SELECT AVG(col1), AVG(col2), AVG(col3), AVG(col4) from table")
avg_c = c.fetchall();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make multiple aggregates per query, like:

```
c.execute("SELECT AVG(col1), AVG(col2), AVG(col3), AVG(col4), AVG(col5), AVG(col6) FROM table")
avg = c.fetchall()[0]
```

The aggregates functions do not have to be per se have to be the same. For example you can select the average of `col1`, the minimum of `col2`, etc.

Using multiple aggregates in the same query is usually better compared to making separate queries each with a specific aggregate, since the number of "round trips" to the database is reduced.